# Opening file php

Tags: php, file, path, include, dependencies

Supposing I have a file called "utils.php" where I open a file for writing or reading:

```
$myfile="myfile.txt";
$fileout=fopen($myfile,'w') or die("Not opened");
```

Now if I have another script **UNDER ANOTHER DIRECTORY**, say "mydir/myscript.php" and I `include` "utils.php" in "myscript.php", **where would the file (try to) be opened from**? The path of "utils.php" or the path of "myscript.php". 
And if it is "myscript.php"'s directory, this means that each script that includes "utils.php" will search for a file called "myfile.txt" in its directory, doesn't it?

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Paths are assumed to be relative to the directory of the script running the command, unless an absolute path is specified (by prefixing the path with '/'), even if the script is being called from somewhere else. So if you specified an include in say, "/var/www/localhost/htdocs/foo.php", the `include` statement would look in the same folder, but within the included file any fopen statements would look within whichever folder that php file was in (unless otherwise specified).

Comment: I am still not perfectly sure if I understood- so my file would be included from mydir/ in the example?

Comment: `include` is a command; `fopen` is a command.  If you `include` a .php file, the script running the `include` command will look for the target .php file in the same directory it is in.  The same goes for any command that references a file; it doesn't matter if `utils.php` was called by `foo.php`, which was called by `bar.php`, which was called by `index.php` etc.  It only matters where *that* `fopen` command is being executed from.

Answer (score 0):

If you `include` a file, the contents of that file will place in the current file. Then, the code will run. Let me say an example. You have four files:

- mydir/

  - index.php:

    ```
    include('../file.php');
    if ($file) {
        echo fgets($file);
        fclose($file);
    }
    ```
  - file.txt

    ```
    mydir directory
    ```
- file.php:

  ```
  $file = @fopen('file.txt', 'r');
  ```
- file.txt

  ```
  base level
  ```

If you run mydir/index.php, first, file.php includes. Then, index.php contains:

```
$file = @fopen('file.txt', 'r');
if ($file) {
    echo fgets($file);
    fclose($file);
}
```

After that, the above code will execute. So, the output is:

```
mydir directory
```